# Computing date from record fields

Tags: sqlite

In an SQLite DB I have a table with a `station` integer field and an `at` date field.

How can I combine these two values to obtain, in a `WHERE` clause a date which is `at` plus `station` months?

I.e. for a record with `at = '2019-01-01'` and `station = 3`, my WHERE clause should look like `WHERE before <= '2019-04-01'`

I have looked at several resources online, including https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html but no one refers to using filed value to compute a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
 WHERE before <=  date(at, (station || ' months') )
```

Please note that according to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> "±NNN months" works by rendering the original date into the YYYY-MM-DD format, adding the ±NNN to the MM month value, then normalizing the result. Thus, for example, the data 2001-03-31 modified by '+1 month' initially yields 2001-04-31, but April only has 30 days so the date is normalized to 2001-05-01. A similar effect occurs when the original date is February 29 of a leapyear and the modifier is ±N years where N is not a multiple of four.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

as in my comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845563/sqlite-equivalent-of-sql-server-dateadd-function

->

```
WHERE before<=date(at,'+'+station+' month')
```

if that doesn't work - try building '+'+station+' month' in a concat statement

date will give you GMT / UTC based value - if you need it for local timezone, use

```
DATETIME(at,'LocalTime', '+'+station+' month')
```

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: SQL string concatenation is '||'.